# LNK1104 Error in Visual Studio Express 2015: Cannot open .exe file

Tags: c, express, visual-studio-2015, fatal-error

I've been troubleshooting this issue for hours to no avail.

Visual Studio will not run any new projects I create. Here's what happens:

1. Say I have the simple "Hello world" program written. When I choose "Run without debugging," the command window will pop up, but nothing will be printed to it.
2. The command window is closed, and I try to run the program again. This time, I get the LNK1104 error, saying

LNK1104 cannot open file 'c:\users\randyprice4\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\pls work\Debug\pls work.exe

If I exit out of Visual Studio and try to delete the entire project, my computer will tell me that the project is being used in another application. The part being used is in

C:\Users\randyprice4\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\pls work\Debug\pls work.exe

The file is being used in System. I cannot kill the debug process or delete the file unless I reset my computer.

I uninstalled Visual Studio and deleted all files associated with it, then reinstalled it, and I am still getting the same error.

If I do ctrl+alt+F7 to rebuild the project, it will build successfully, but that's about the only positive thing that's happening.

I'm at a loss. Help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: The following are not the issue:

-Task Manager (doesn't appear in task manager)

-Antivirus

Comment: Make sure the program isn't running in Task Manager.

Comment: it is possible that you forget to initialize a variable. and you are using it for memory allocation or in a loop. or something that can consume system resources (memory, time, file access ...)

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is in the code.  However, without the code being posted, we can do nothing but guess.

Comment: many of the windows tools are very uncooperative when there is a space in the file name and/or in a directory path name.  That would be the first thing I would change.   Suggest create a standalone application with debug info, such as for the 'hello world' application, then run that using the debugger.

Comment: @user3629249 The program code is irrelevant - visual studio will not run ANYTHING. The debug running in system will not close.

Comment: The meaning of "The file is being used in System" is unclear to me.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The application part of the program that constitutes the .exe file won't stop running

Comment: You can inspect its threads with `procexp` (or a full-fledged debugger; `procexp` can be configured to use symbols FYI) to see where it's stuck.

Comment: The primary concern, however, is the "debugger". Normally, VS launches the process as its child. So, something running it from a SYSTEM-owned process is not normal (at least, for the VS versions I had experience with). So, first and foremost, find out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Theories:

- the file being used by System most probably means that some intrusive resident code (like an anti-virus) is opening it and interfering with your actions. You may use [`procmon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see all the operations that happen with your program's file (and, for the suspicious System activity, see relevant stacktraces). This may very well be a virus, FYI (in which case, you might not be able to run `procmon` at all).
- your program itself does something funny and keeps running after the console window closes. Though, if it's a simple "Hello, world" in a freshly-created project with default settings, this is very unlikely unless the aforementioned "virus" has augmented it in some way. Still, you can check this with [`procexp`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer).